# Using Bayes' theorem

Tags: proof-verification, bayes-theorem

Think I've managed to get it but not 100% sure

The probability that Ted is late for work on a rainy day is 0.4 and the probability that he is
late for work on a non-rainy day is 0.1. The probability that it will rain tomorrow is 0.6.
What is the probability that it did not rain if Eddy was late at work?

I've said $P($Late given it rains)$=0.4$ $P($Late given it doesn't rains)$=0.1$ 
    $P$(Rains tommorow)$= 0.6$

I've then worked out $P$(Late on any day)$= 0.28$
$P$(no rain given late)$= ($P(Late given no rain)*P(no rain))/P(late) = $(0.4*0.1)/(0.28)$ = 1/7

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer to question I will outline the method

We want to compute the following,
$$
P(\text{No Rain}|\text{Late})
$$
What information do we have
$$
P(\text{Late}|\text{Rain}) = 0.4,\\
P(\text{Late}|\text{No Rain}) = 0.1,\\
P(\text{Rain}) = 0.6 \implies P(\text{No Rain}) = 1 - P(\text{Rain})  = 0.4
$$
We can use Bayes to define the following
$$
P(\text{No Rain}|\text{Late})P(\text{Late}) = P(\text{Late}|\text{No Rain})P(\text{No Rain})
$$
or
$$
P(\text{No Rain}|\text{Late})= \frac{P(\text{Late}|\text{No Rain})P(\text{No Rain})}{P(\text{Late}) }
$$
The only information we are missing is $P(\text{Late})$
This is computed by
$$
P(\text{Late}) = P(\text{Late}|\text{No Rain})P(\text{No Rain}) + P(\text{Late}|\text{Rain})P(\text{Rain})
$$
we are no ready
$$
P(\text{Late}) = 0.1 \times 0.4 + 0.4\times0.6 = \frac{28}{100}
$$
Now putting it int o the equation we want
$$
P(\text{No Rain}|\text{Late})= \frac{\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{4}{10}}{\frac{28}{100}} = \frac{4}{28} = \frac{1}{7}
$$
So the answer is correct.

Comment: Realised that was a typing error. I meant P(late on any day).

Comment: ok. I will remove that part.